# Appending mutiple image on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to add the same image on a div five times but when I open my web page in Chrome or any browser it only shows one smiley.png image when it supposed to show five smiley.png on different coordinates on a the leftSide div. I am not sure what is the problem with my code below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Web Practice 2</title>
     <style type="text/css">
      img {
       position: absolute;
      }
      div {
       width: 500px;
       height: 500px;
       position: absolute;
      }
      #rightSide {
       left: 500px;
       border-left: 1px solid black;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="leftSide"></div>
     <div id="rightSide"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var numberOfFaces = 5;
      var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    
      function generate() {
       for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "smile.png");
        img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);
        img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);
        theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
       }
      }
    
      window.onload = generate();
    
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @haim770 I have changed it to `generate` only thank you for that info, but still it doesn't display five images only one.

Comment: The coordinates need a unit, e.g. pixels or percentage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually *are* five images, but it only appears like there is one because your position randomization is not working correctly (in other words, the images are all being stacked on top of each other). The CSS `top` and `left` attributes require units, so you should append `"px"` to both.

Also, note that since the necessary DOM has already loaded by the time your script begins executing, you don't need to use `window.onload` at all.

Lastly, you might be pleased to know that you can use the shortcut `img.src = ...` instead of calling `img.setAttribute("src", ...)` in your script.

---

### Demo Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Practice 2</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    div {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="leftSide"></div>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generate() {
      for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "smile.png";
        img.alt = "Smile!"
        img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + "px";
        img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + "px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
      }
    }

    generate();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. You need to assign a function *reference* to `window.onload`. When you're using `generate()`, you're *invoking* the function and since it doesn't `return` anything you're effectively doing `window.onload = undefined`.
2. You're assigning `theLeftSide` before the DOM is ready, hence it will always be `null` and will throw upon your `appendChild()` calls.

Try this instead:

```
  var numberOfFaces = 5;

  function generate() {
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.setAttribute("src", "smile.png");
      img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 450);
      img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 450);
      theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
    }
  }

  window.onload = generate;
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5gomo6j/)

Comment: There is a third problem as well - no units of measurement provided for the `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add units of measure ("px" for pixels) to the coordinates. Without units specified, the property values are invalid.

Also, you are calling `generate` immediately, rather than referring to the function.

I have modified your sizes to fit better in the stack overflow snippet space and also used the more correct `.addEventListener` method for setting up your `load` event handler. Also, I have added a temporary background color to the `div` elements to better see the layout of the pictures in the `leftSide` element.

```js
      var numberOfFaces = 5;
      var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    
      function generate() {
       for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "smile.png");
        img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*250) + "px";
        img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*250) + "px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
       }
      }
    
      window.addEventListener("load", generate);
```

```css
      img {
       position: absolute;
      }
      div {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       position: absolute;
          background-color:#ff0;
      }
      #rightSide {
       left: 350px;
       border-left: 1px solid black;
      }
```

```html
     <div id="leftSide"></div>
     <div id="rightSide"></div>
```

Comment: That is very informative thank you, same as gyre I missed out the "px" I will try this out in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue, I just changed `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `<html>` and it worked but I am not sure why though.

Comment: That is not correct. You should have `<!DOCTYPE html>`. When you remove it, the browser does not know what version of HTML you are trying to be compatible with and so it goes into "Quirks Mode", which is a way of parsing the document that goes back to before there were any hard standards to HTML. This results in varying results across different browsers. You should add the `DOCTYPE` to put the browser back into "standards mode" and then correct your coding issues as we have described below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you that is very informative, I will take note of that.